# How to check if couchbase document exists, without retrieving full content, using golang SDK?

Tags: go, couchbase, gocb

In my code I want to do or not to do some actions depending on document with given key existence. But can't avoid additional network overhead retrieving all document content.

Now I'm using

```
cas, err := bucket.Get(key, &value)
```

And looking for `err == gocb.ErrKeyNotFound` to determine document missed case.

Is there some more efficient approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [sub-document API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/sdk/go/document-operations.html#story-h2-7) and check for the existence of a field.

Example from [Using the Sub-Document API to get (only) what you want](https://blog.couchbase.com/subdoc-explained/)
:

```
rv = bucket.lookup_in('customer123', SD.exists('purchases.pending[-1]'))
rv.exists(0) # (check if path for first command exists): =&gt;; False
```

**Edit: Add go example**

You can use the sub-document API to check for document existence like this:

```
frag, err := bucket.LookupIn("document-key").
    Exists("any-path").Execute()

if err != nil && err == gocb.ErrKeyNotFound {
    fmt.Printf("Key does not exist\n")
} else {
    if frag.Exists("any-path") {
        fmt.Printf("Path exists\n")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Path does not exist\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case document can have no fields, or some of them. It's a map actually and I can't know for sure that particular field is exists

Comment: @mind_religion, please see my edit. You can still use the sub-document API in your situation. Perhaps a feature request is in order, to add something to `gocb.Bucket`: [Couchbase Go SDK Issue Tracker](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/GOCBC).

Comment: But how we handle if real error with cb happens here?